# RN debugger UI not showing profiler & components tab for Android device

Tags: react-native

I am fairly new to RN world. I am trying to figure out one problem in my RN app (non-expo app). The app runs on Web & Android platform. When i wanted to do some debugging on the app, I am using RN debugger UI. Since i have installed React Developer tools extension, for web platform, I am able to see Profiler tab in the debugger pane. But i am not able to see those tabs when i am trying to do the debugging from an Android app.

Things i have done so far,

Debug Android build installed, clicked on the `Debug` option from developer settings activity. Debugger UI is opening with extension is installed. But no sign of profiler tab

Tried all the possible ways like reinstalling the app, clearing the cache of metro bundler.

Tried reinstalling chrome extension but still no luck

In some of the stack overflow threads, They have mentioned to change the theme of profiler, but still no luck. Did the defaults reset nothing happened.

Set the localhost port for debugging in developer settings activity and restarted the app. Still no luck.

Here is the details of my environment

```
"react-dom": "17.0.2",

"react": "17.0.2",

"react-native": "0.66.5",

"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.66.2",

"react-native-bundle-visualizer": "3.1.1",

"typescript": "4.9.4",
```

Consider that i cannot update the major react versions as a fix for this since the project is fairly large.